# ui-router: ui-sref not changing font color

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I looked at almost all the questions associated and gave a shot to change the font color of a navigation link using ui-router's ui-sref functionality. However, I don't see the change in font color but I do see change in the background color when I add that to .active class inside css. 
I would appreciate If someone could point out what is wrong with the following. I just want to change the font color when the route is active. i.e.

```
<nav>
            <ul>

                <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: activeListItem == 'home'}"> <a ui-sref="Home "><img src="images/icon-information.png"> Introduction </a>  </li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: activeListItem == 'testInfo'}"> <a  ui-sref ="TestInfo"> <img src="images/icon-settings.png"> SmartCart Setup</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: activeListItem =='errorScenarios'}" > <a ui-sref="ErrorScenarios"><img src="images/icon-error.png"> Error Scenarios </a> </li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"  ng-class="{active: activeListItem == 'contactUs'}" > <a  ui-sref="ContactUs"><img src="images/icon-contact.png"> Contact </a> </li>

            </ul>

</nav>
```

My css has the following

```
body {  
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 0px;
}


a {
  color: #F04a24;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #F04a24;
}

a:hover {
  color: #512b83;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #512b83;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 3em;
}

h2 {
  color: #512b83;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
  color: #512b83;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.panel-heading h3, .panel-heading h4 {
  color: #512b83;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
    font-size: 1em;
}

nav a { 
    border-bottom: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #512b83;
}

nav a:hover {   
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #512b83;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

nav li img{
    width: 20px;
}



.active 
{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Please show your JS as well or create a plunker/fiddle.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/QLtyn4Ji5uJzF7Cd7Kjt?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its an issue with your CSS.
I created a fork of your plunker where its working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OWp8jAJqNAmfnzCCklTX?p=preview

```
 li:hover,li:focus, li.active {
     background:blue;
  }
```

Please note that it should be li.active  .
"active" is a class inside "li" tag and not a property like hover or focus. So it should be a "." rather than ":".

Comment: When a page/link is active I would like to see the text color of the navigation link change not the background of the link. As I originally stated. I added color to the plunker you sent. However, it doesn't change the color of text when the page is active.   li:hover,li:focus, li.active {
      color: red;
  }

Comment: It still has to do with CSS. The text is within anchor tag (<a>), hence you have to set the CSS accordingly. li.active > a {color:red}.I have updated the CSS in my plunker. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i've done mine

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <h5 class="sideNav-title">Main Menu</h5>
    <li class="customNav active" ui-sref-active="active" ng-show="shell.adminAccess"><a ui-sref="dashboard"><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="customNav" ui-sref-active="active" ng-show="shell.adminAccess"><a ui-sref="userManagement"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> User-Management</a></li>
    <li class="customNav" ><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseAttendance" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseAttendance"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Attendance <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

My Ccs hope it helps.

```
li.customNav > a:hover,li.active.customNav > a,li.current.customNav > a {
background-color: @main_color !important;
color: #ffffff !important;
border-left: 2.5px solid @primary_color;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.20), 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
```

}

Comment: It still doesn't change the text color for me. I picked your css as well as li but didn't help.